# Setting up apache server in virtualbox guest?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

Could someone Please help me set up Debian (Guest) as the apache server so that I could access it from Host, as well as the guest could access outside internet ?

I am getting stuck with setting the network connections and cannot find any solution to the problem.

It is possible right ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the Virtual Box config for the machine, adding a second network interface, which is 'host-only'. This provides access from your computer to the VM, through the new 'vboxnet0' interface you can see on your computer with `ifconfig -a`

Comment: Thanks. I can access host from guest, but I am not able to access the guest from host.

Comment: Did your vboxnet0 network adapter get an IP?